# Mysql CREATEUSER command through php

Tags: php, mysql, createuser

So I am trying to add users to my server that can login through the mysql_connect(host,username,password) command. I currently have

```
$str = "CREATE USER '.$name.'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '.$encryption.'"
$query = mysql_query($str);
```

When I run this on my server with the variables manually plugged in, the query works. When I run this through php it doesn't. Is my formatting incorrect?

Comment: The formatting does not seems to be good and you may also have permission differences. The php user may not have enough permissions to create mysql users.

Comment: In this scenario I am using the root user. So I have full permission.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of those dots . in the query.  You are using doubles quotes and not breaking out of them:

```
$str = "CREATE USER '$name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$encryption'";
```

Comment: Also, if you are actually supplying the hash instead of the plaintext password, you need: `IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '$encryption'`